# Write input of a npm command to a variable but only a specific part

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, rhel, npm-scripts

On my root directory of my project, I have a package.json. While doing the CI build, I am trying to capture the version properties from the file. Since I am running on a node container, the following command is possible.

> `node -p -e require('./package.json').version`

I included the above in scripts property of package.json

```
  "scripts": {
     "version": "node -p -e require('./package.json').version"
   },
```

I am capturing it in a variable using

> `export VERSION=$(npm run version)`

which seems to capture a lot more than the result of the npm command. Build environment is a Nodejs10 container built on rhel7.

**jq** is not available and something without it may be better

Any suggestions?

Comment: **1)** Change your npm script to: `"version": "node -p \"require('./package.json').version\""` - The `-e` option is not necessary, also the js to be evaluated must be passed as a string. Note it's been encased in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"`. **2)** Also capture and export it using the following code instead; `export VERSION=$(npm run version -s)` - note the additional `-s` option (which is the shorthand for [`--silent`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)) - this ensures you capture only the version (e.g. `1.0.0`) and not the additional npm log info.

Comment: Thanks RobC. Exactly what I was looking for. You may post it as a answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

1. Change your npm script to:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "version": "node -p \"require('./package.json').version\""
   }
   ```

   The `-e` option is not necessary, also the JavaScript to be evaluated must be passed as a string. Note it's been encased in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"`.
2. Also capture and export it using the following code instead:

   ```sh
   export VERSION=$(npm run version -s)
   ```

   Note the additional `-s` option (which is the shorthand for [`--silent`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)) - this ensures you capture only the version (e.g. `1.0.0`) and not the additional npm log info.

Answer (score 0):

packege.json can reference itself using the following pattern

`$npm_package_PROP[_SUB_PROP][_SUB_SUB_PROP]`

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "version": "echo $npm_package_version"
  },
```

```sh
npm run version # output: 1.0.0
```

Comment: What is the NPM version you are using?